# Custom config loading in Go

Tags: json, go, config

I'm using JSON files to store/load my config. Let's say I have the following:

```
type X interface

// implements interface X
type Y struct {
    Value string
}

// implements interface X
type Z struct {
    Value string
}

type Config struct {
    interfaceInstance X `json:"X"`
}
```

Config file example:

```
{
  "config1": {
    "X": {
      "type": "Z",
      "Value": "value_1"
    }
  },


  "config2": {
    "X": {
      "type": "Y",
      "Value": "value_2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to define config files something like this example, and be able to dynamically load the JSON as either struct `Y` or struct `Z`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I'm using a simple `json.Decoder` to load the JSON as a struct.

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
err = decoder.Decode(&config)
```

Comment: If you know beforehand what the type is, e.g. you know that `config2.X.type` is `Y`, then you can just pre-allocate the correct type. If you don't know the type beforehand you can implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

Comment: Don't know the type beforehand. You can't implement `Unmarshaler` on an interface, isn't it? Or are you saying to implement `Unmarshal` for `type Config` and custom assign ALL fields in the struct (there's more than just `interfaceInstance`)

Comment: Yes, implement `Unmarshaler` for `Config` type, and yes, based on the value of the `"type"` key you'll have to pre-allocate however many `interfaceInstance` fields you have. If you use interface fields the `encoding/json` decoder has no way of knowing what type you want there. If that's too inconvenient try rethinking the design of your config file or Config type.

Comment: ... btw don't use field names starting with lowercase (`interfaceInstance`) if you want to encode/decode them. User defined symbols that start with a lowercase letter are unexported. Change it to `InterfaceInstance`

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy would be to implement `json.Unmarshaler` for the `Config` type in such a way that you first unmarshal into a generic object and inspect the "type" attribute then, switching on the type string, unmarshal the same byte array into the known type and assign to the "interfaceInstance" member of the config.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/04jtRt4fyo7)):

```
// Note the slightly different JSON here...
var jsonstr = `{
  "config1": {
    "type": "Z",
    "Value": "value_1"
  },
  "config2": {
    "type": "Y",
    "Value": "value_2"
  }
}`

func main() {
  config := map[string]Config{}
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &config)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("OK: %#v\n", config)
  // OK: map[string]main.Config{
  //   "config1": main.Config{interfaceInstance:main.Z{Value:"value_1"}},
  //   "config2": main.Config{interfaceInstance:main.Y{Value:"value_2"}},
  // }
}

func (c *Config) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
  // Unmarshal into an object to inspect the type.
  var obj map[string]interface{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &obj)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // Unmarshal again into the target type.
  configType := obj["type"].(string)
  switch configType {
  case "Y":
    var y Y
    if err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &y); err == nil {
      c.interfaceInstance = y
    }
  case "Z":
    var z Z
    if err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &z); err == nil {
      c.interfaceInstance = z
    }
  default:
    return fmt.Errorf("unexpected type %q", configType)
  }
  return err
}
```